# Facebook Audience Network Reporting API returned no data

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to get data out of the Facebook API and the [Audience Network Reporting API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api).

I have followed the steps to create a System User Access Token however any request does not return any data. e.g.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{business_id}/adnetworkanalytics/?metrics=['fb_ad_network_imp']&access_token={access_token}`

Other simpler request as a `/me` work correctly and there is definitely data to be queried which indicates that this is likely one of two issues:

There is a mention somewhere that certain API calls do not work on apps that are not live however there isn't much information on this.

Steps taken to create the app/system user:

1. Created a new app
2. Configured the business manager and advertising accounts
3. Added new system user and added the user to the app along with the ad accounts
4. Create an access token for the system user along with the correct access including `read_audience_network_insights_ads`

Question:

Has anyone had any experience with empty data being returned and how to resolve it or how this should be correctly configured? I think it's likely one of:

1. A configuration issue with the app and system user
2. An issue with the request however I have tried a number of different requests from the documentation

Cheers!

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: Has anyone had a similar experience with empty data being returned from this part of the API and how to resolve it or how this should be correctly configured?

Comment: I have resolved this as it is actually the Marketing API data I wanted. There was no data because this feature was not being used 

Comment: Hi @mrsnlke , I'm trying to use the same API and I have the same issue. Which is the Business ID? Because If I use the Account ID I get the error ""(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (adnetworkanalytics) on node type (AdAccount)". Thank you in advance!